# How to calculate difference between two dates using Global PHP field?

Tags: views

I have a *global PHP* field provided by [views php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) module. I tried two functions to calculate the date difference, date_diff() and $fieldDate->difference() but it always gives me an ajax error.
I think it causes by date format of the date field but I don't know how to fix it. What is right here?

```
$today=date("m/d/Y"); 
$load = $data->field_field_date_loading[0]['raw']['value'];
$diff=date_diff($load,$today);
echo $diff->format("%R%a days");
```

or

```
$today=date("m/d/Y"); 
$load = $data->field_field_date_loading[0]['raw']['value'];
$diff = $load->difference($today, 'days');
echo $diff;
```

Comment: You can try with Computed Fields[https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field] module

Comment: @latikas but the fields are from differents nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) is a formatting function, if you want to use [date_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php) your code needs to be something like:

```
$today = new DateTime();
$load = new DateTime($data->field_field_date_loading[0]['raw']['value']);
$diff = date_diff($load, $today);
```